# Streaming 4k videos from ubuntu server via DLNA

Tags: ubuntu, video, streaming, tv, dlna

I am running an ubuntu server in my LAN. Streaming videos and music was done with [mediatomb](http://mediatomb.cc/) but it looks like the server denied sending UHD videos. I also tried [MiniDLNA](http://minidlna.sourceforge.net/) but ended up with the same problem.

As testing devices I used an [LG 55UF6809](http://www.lg.com/de/tv/lg-55UF6809) and an older Panasonic TV, which has no UHD capabilities but was still unable to play the video. That made me think the issue is probably with the Server and not with the TVs. UHD content from Netflix plays fine.

The server is an [HP ProLiant MicroServer Gen7](http://www8.hp.com/h20195/v2/GetPDF.aspx/c04111079.pdf). The network is definitely fast enough to stream content. The files are stored on a WD Red, if that matters. Playing the files on a PC over Samba or NFS share works well too.

Any ideas on how to stream UHD videos within my network?

Answer (score 0):

[Plex](https://plex.tv/) is a media streaming application with a free media server that can function as a DLNA server and [supports 4k](https://support.plex.tv/hc/en-us/articles/207339358-Does-Plex-Media-Player-have-support-for-4K-).  It runs on Linux (as well as Windows, OSX, and NAS devices).

[Here's a guide](https://support.plex.tv/hc/en-us/articles/200350536-DLNA) for setting up DLNA with Plex.

Comment: Plex has really high cpu and memory usage. I tried it before but it ran really slow. Are the mediatomb and minidlna both unable do stream 4k? I would like to stick with a lightweight server because I don't need all of the functionality of Plex. Obviously if there is no other option I'll try this again :)

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know the other two you mention so I can only expand a bit on Plex. How did it run really slow? Was it through DLNA? I totally understand you want something lightweight, but for me personally the ease of using/installing Plex was just more important.

Comment: The server was running on 60% CPU on idle. Streaming files was lagging. I am pretty sure it was because of transcoding. Is it possible to disable transcoding in Plex? I'll give it another go tonight and let you know

Comment: Yes, you can enable direct play, but I'm not sure if it works with DLNA as I've never tried that.

Comment: As it tourns out the plex dlna does not stream 4k videos in this case either.  Neither is the plex app for my Smart TV

Answer (score 0):

My server runs Debian, which isn't that different fro Ubuntu, and I use MiniDLNA without problems, even for 4K and HDR content.
This worked with both my old Samsung TV als my less old LG TV, and it works from a Windows computer browsing UPNP with VLC Media player.

You could try installing BubbleUPnP on a smartphone and/or VLC on computer and see if that works to establish that it's not a TV issue.